# Display all user profiles in variable

Tags: cmd

I need the output of all User profiles only with their names without the first column "All User Profile"
Example:

```
All User Profile    : WifiName
Output:
WifiName
```

I am using:

```
for /f %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile | find /i "all user profile"') do set "%%~a"
echo %a% > C:\test.txt
```

Comment: `(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ... do echo/%%b) > C:\test.txt`

Comment: Nothing is happening unfortunately. I do not even receive errors.

(for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (netsh wlan show profile | find /i "All user profile") do echo/%%b) > C:\test.txt

Comment: You need to escape the pipe like `^|` as it's in `for /F`; I didn't spot that earlier...

Answer (score 1):

`@echo off`

`for /f "tokens=2 skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('netsh wlan show profile') do echo %%a >> .\test.txt`